# How does sqlachemy query method work?

Tags: python, syntax, sqlalchemy

I am learning sqlachemy, I'm relatively new to Python.

When I read its documentation, I saw [this kind of usage](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/tutorial.html#common-filter-operators), for example:

> query.filter(User.name == 'ed')

Wouldn't Python evaluate the expression `User.name == 'ed'` and then pass the result, which is a boolean, to `query.filter` method?

How does this kind of syntax work? Does Python support some kind of operator overriding like C++?

Comment: if you're feeling ambitious, read section 20.5 here: http://www.aosabook.org/en/sqlalchemy.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SQLAlchemy uses the various [special method hooks](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#basic-customization) to overload operator behaviour.

For `==`, the `__eq__()` method returns special objects that signify a SQL expression when compiled. To quote the documentation on the 'rich comparison' hooks:

> By convention, `False` and `True` are returned for a successful comparison. However, these methods can return any value, so if the comparison operator is used in a Boolean context (e.g., in the condition of an `if` statement), Python will call `bool()` on the value to determine if the result is true or false.

See the [`ColumnOperators` class](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/blob/main/lib/sqlalchemy/sql/operators.py#L429) in the SQLAlchemy source for the specific hooks implemented.