# How does SQLAlchemy implement filter like methods?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have been taking a look at some SQL Alchemy queries. From the [documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.filter), you can use this kind of queries:

```py
session.query(MyClass).filter(MyClass.name == 'some name')
```

How can they evaluate the `MyClass.name == 'some name'` as an expression? My instinct says that it should be first evaluated to some `Bool` but that would make no sense because then the filtering is basically useless.

How to implement something like that in `python`?

Comment: It's based on [descriptors](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html) (different behaviour in class and instance context) and operator overloading, `__eq__` in this case. I think there was a good answer to this on SO, trying to look for it.

Comment: This is not exactly it, but close https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57040151/how-is-precedence-grouping-implemented-in-sqlalchemy

Comment: awesome, that was exactly what I wanted. I should have supposed it was like that ofc. Thank you so much.

Comment: This is what I remembered https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15701804/how-does-sqlachemy-query-method-work